# Converting BigDecimal to Integer

Tags: java, integer, casting, bigdecimal

I have Hibernate method which returns me a BigDecimal.
I have another API method to which I need to pass that number but it accepts Integer as parameter. I cannot change return types or variable types of both methods.

Now how to convert the BigDecimal into Integer and pass it to second method?

Is there a way out of this?

Comment: I corrected your title. This is *conversion,* not *casting.*

Answer (score 231, accepted):

You would call [`myBigDecimal.intValueExact()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#intValueExact--) (or just [`intValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#intValue--)) and it will even throw an exception if you would lose information. That returns an int but autoboxing takes care of that.

Comment: `intValueExact()` is a good recommendation; it was added in 1.5

Comment: Calling `intValue()` is dangerous unless you are 100% bet your life on it positive that the number is within the `Integer` range.

Comment: Does this makes sense: "Integer.valueOf(myBigDecimal.intValueExact())"?

Answer (score 34):

Can you guarantee that the [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal) will never contain a value larger than [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)?

If yes, then here's your code calling [`intValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#intValue--):

```
Integer.valueOf(bdValue.intValue())
```

Comment: Yes. I guess it will not contain larger value than Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: There's no reason to do the valueOf other than to get an Object instead of a primitive right?

Comment: I would say this should be the official answer because a. mentions the limits, b. prevents autoboxing.

Answer (score 27):

**TL;DR**

Use one of these for universal conversion needs

```
//Java 7 or below
bigDecimal.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN).intValueExact()
//Java 8    
bigDecimal.toBigInteger().intValueExact()
```

**Reasoning**

The answer depends on what the requirements are and how you answer these question.

- Will the `BigDecimal` potentially have a non-zero fractional part?
- Will the `BigDecimal` potentially not fit into the `Integer` range?
- Would you like non-zero fractional parts rounded or truncated?
- How would you like non-zero fractional parts rounded?

If you answered no to the first 2 questions, you could just use `BigDecimal.intValueExact()` as others have suggested and let it blow up when something unexpected happens.

If you are not absolutely 100% confident about question number 2, then `intValue()` is *always* the wrong answer.

**Making it better**

Let's use the following assumptions based on the other answers.

- We are okay with losing precision and truncating the value because that's what `intValueExact()` and auto-boxing do
- We want an exception thrown when the `BigDecimal` is larger than the `Integer` range because anything else would be crazy unless you have a very specific need for the wrap around that happens when you drop the high-order bits.

Given those params, `intValueExact()` throws an exception when we don't want it to if our fractional part is non-zero.  On the other hand, `intValue()` doesn't throw an exception when it should if our `BigDecimal` is too large.

To get the best of both worlds, round off the `BigDecimal` first, then convert.  This also has the benefit of giving you more control over the rounding process.

**Spock Groovy Test**

```Java
void 'test BigDecimal rounding'() {
    given:
    BigDecimal decimal = new BigDecimal(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1.99)
    BigDecimal hugeDecimal = new BigDecimal(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1.99)
    BigDecimal reallyHuge = new BigDecimal("10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
    String decimalAsBigIntString = decimal.toBigInteger().toString()
    String hugeDecimalAsBigIntString = hugeDecimal.toBigInteger().toString()
    String reallyHugeAsBigIntString = reallyHuge.toBigInteger().toString()

    expect: 'decimals that can be truncated within Integer range to do so without exception'
    //GOOD: Truncates without exception
    '' + decimal.intValue() == decimalAsBigIntString
    //BAD: Throws ArithmeticException 'Non-zero decimal digits' because we lose information
    // decimal.intValueExact() == decimalAsBigIntString
    //GOOD: Truncates without exception
    '' + decimal.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN).intValueExact() == decimalAsBigIntString

    and: 'truncated decimal that cannot be truncated within Integer range throw conversionOverflow exception'
    //BAD: hugeDecimal.intValue() is -2147483648 instead of 2147483648
    //'' + hugeDecimal.intValue() == hugeDecimalAsBigIntString
    //BAD: Throws ArithmeticException 'Non-zero decimal digits' because we lose information
    //'' + hugeDecimal.intValueExact() == hugeDecimalAsBigIntString
    //GOOD: Throws conversionOverflow ArithmeticException because to large
    //'' + hugeDecimal.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN).intValueExact() == hugeDecimalAsBigIntString

    and: 'truncated decimal that cannot be truncated within Integer range throw conversionOverflow exception'
    //BAD: hugeDecimal.intValue() is 0
    //'' + reallyHuge.intValue() == reallyHugeAsBigIntString
    //GOOD: Throws conversionOverflow ArithmeticException because to large
    //'' + reallyHuge.intValueExact() == reallyHugeAsBigIntString
    //GOOD: Throws conversionOverflow ArithmeticException because to large
    //'' + reallyHuge.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN).intValueExact() == reallyHugeAsBigIntString

    and: 'if using Java 8, BigInteger has intValueExact() just like BigDecimal'
    //decimal.toBigInteger().intValueExact() == decimal.setScale(0, RoundingMode.DOWN).intValueExact()
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Well, you could call [`BigDecimal.intValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#intValue%28%29):

> Converts this BigDecimal to an int. This conversion is analogous to a narrowing primitive conversion from double to short as defined in the Java Language Specification: any fractional part of this BigDecimal will be discarded, and if the resulting "BigInteger" is too big to fit in an int, only the low-order 32 bits are returned. Note that this conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude and precision of this BigDecimal value as well as return a result with the opposite sign.

You can then either explicitly call `Integer.valueOf(int)` or let auto-boxing do it for you if you're using a sufficiently recent version of Java.

Answer (score 9):

Following should do the trick:

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(10);
int i = d.intValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling [BigInteger#intValue()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#intValue%28%29) ?

Answer (score 0):

See [BigDecimal#intValue()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#intValue%28%29)

Answer (score -4):

I found that the above did not work for me. I was pulling a cell value from a JTable but could not cast to double or int etc. My solution:

```
Object obj = getTable().getValueAt(row, 0);
```

where row 0 would always be a number. Hope this helps anyone still scrolling!