# ClassCastException and incompatible

Tags: java, classcastexception

In a method I remember there was an error thrown at a line having the following code.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

at

```
Integer count = (Integer) result[1];
```

and I replaced the code to

```
Integer count = ((BigDecimal) result[1]).intValue();
```

the error has gone.

But some how I got the following error for the same code snippets in the new project.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal incompatible with java.lang.Integer
```

Just wanted to know, both of these are the same or not.

Comment: It's very hard to help you without knowing what `result` is...

Comment: If you got the same error for the same code snippet, more often than not, it is the same problem and the same solution would be applicable.

Comment: what is the type of result array?

Comment: For the incompatible error: _This exception is recevied when using Interchange Server Relationship APIs in WPS with Oracle as the database._ in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1JR31122 made me asking this question.

Comment: Were you found `java.math.Integer`? In java there is no such...

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan: It was a mistake.

Comment: And which is "original" type of `result[1]`?

Comment: Obviously, if the outcome of two program snippest is different under otherwise equal conditions, the snippets are not "the same".

Answer (score 0):

Both are not same 
`Integer count = (Integer) result[1];` tries to cast the BigDecimal Object to the Integer. Will thorw an exception always.

`Integer count = ((BigDecimal) result[1]).intValue();` this will work if your result has BigDecimal Object.

Better you check you have compiled your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Integer count = ((BigDecimal) result[1]).intValueExact();
```

Or: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/math/bigdecimal_intvalueexact.htm

Answer (score 0):

BigDecimal.intValueExact() (or BigDecimal.intValue()) :

> Converts this BigDecimal to an int. This conversion is analogous to a narrowing primitive conversion from double to short as defined in the Java Language Specification: any fractional part of this BigDecimal will be discarded, and if the resulting "BigInteger" is too big to fit in an int, only the low-order 32 bits are returned. Note that this conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude and precision of this BigDecimal value as well as return a result with the opposite sign.

Plase take into consideration that BigDecimal may contain values which are larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Reference: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043579/converting-bigdecimal-to-integer)