# Fetching specific columns using list() hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, criteria

I have Hibernate `criteria` query as follows:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Test.class);
ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
projList.add(Projections.property("Month"));
projList.add(Projections.property("Year"));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(projList));
```

Here I am trying to fetch distinct values using Month and year similar to

`select distinct Month, Year from table;`

And finally after complete query I am using `list()` to fetch the criteria as:

`criteriaList = criteria.list();`

Now I have the `criteriaList` as `Object` with two column data `Month` and `Year`. I want to list the results of the query in `criteriaList` with only `Month` into a `List<Integer>`.

I have tried looping through the `criteriaList` and converting the fetched `Object` to `List<Integer>`, but it didn't work. How can I get only first column (`Month)` from the returned two columns?

**Note:** Setting projections to only one column `(Month)` will not help as I need distinct on both `Month` and `Year`

**Update:**

I have used the following types:

```
List<Object[]> criteriaList = Collections.emptyList();
List<Integer> Month = Collections.emptyList();
```

And since the number of months returned would be varying, I would like to add the fetched Months into a `List<Integer>` to perform further operations on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `ProjectionList` as you shown, hibernate returns `List<Object[]>` on `criteria.list()`. In your case, object array first element (0 index) is month, and second element (1 index) is year.

So you have to deal with a list of object array, as following:

```
List<Object[]> criteriaList = criteria.list();
List<Integer> monthList = Collections.emptyList();

for (Object[] row : criteriaList) {
    try{
        BigDecimal month = row[0];
        monthList.add(month.intValueExact());
    catch(Exception e){
        //To deal with casting Exception, NPE and 
        //ArithmeticException if int conversion fails
    }

    //Do what you want ...
}
```

Of course, I am supposing `Projections.property("Month")` is an `Integer` object, but I don't know, so you have to cast properly. The same for `Year`.

Of course, you can also use a resultTransformer.

## Edit

I just edited my suggested block after you give more information on your comments.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please suggest something based on my updated question?

Comment: What is the type of `month` property in `Test.class`?

Comment: I got the point and changed the type of month list to `List<BigDecimal> Month = Collections.emptyList();` but while adding `row[0]` to `Month` I get `UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: Well, try to cast to `BigDecimal` in a temporal variable, and then convert to `Integer` in order to add to the list. See this for conversion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043579/converting-bigdecimal-to-integer

Comment: But when I get the value in `criteria.list()` its object, and if I am looping through the `Object[]` can I not directly add it to the `list`, of course after casting `Integer` to it?

Comment: I edited my answer, it is not clear to me what do you want to do, but I think this answer your question.

Comment: Yes I did the same. Thanks for help. Since your answer is similar to what I already did, accepting your answer.