# How to convert an Big decimal number to integer

Tags: android, bigdecimal

I am calculating the speed and number of calories burned in my app for which I have to convert this number  **7.813094473379822E-4**  to just **7**. How should I convert this? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting BigDecimal to Integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043579/converting-bigdecimal-to-integer)

Comment: `7.813094473379822E-4` does not equal `7`, so why would you want to make it `7`? Converting this value to an integer would result in `0`.

Comment: kk so can i round it to  8

Comment: @saipavan: no not "round it to 8". You don't seem to understand that `7.81...E-4` is another way to write `0.000781...`. Rounding that to an integer results in `0`, not `7` or `8`.

Comment: i really lost my mind, thanks  a lot for making me understand

Answer (score 2):

To get the integer value from a 
`BigDecimal`instance you can use [BigDecimal#intValue(](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#intValue()))